# An error occurred while saving the category on Magento2

Tags: magento2, category, save

when I try to save a category I get this error from the backoffice. Here is the error related to this action:

> Blockquote
> [2021-11-24 10:52:02] main.CRITICAL: DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (23/11/2021) at position 0 (2): Unexpected character {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (23/11/2021) at position 0 (2): Unexpected character at /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Stdlib/DateTime.php:58)"} []

Have you ever had the problem? I am using magento 2.4.2. I tried reindexing but still nothing

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Check the `$date` argument passed to `formatDate()`. I think (23/11/2021) is wrong, it should look something like  [2021-11-23 10:52:02]